# Assigning an IP address but error

Tags: powershell

I am setting the IP address but received the following error message:

```
+CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument (.....) (....), CimException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 87, New-NETIPAddress
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code. Include the full, unmutilated error message.

Comment: Your question doesn't go into much detail or contain any of the code you are using. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question that will get you a good answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Already found my mistake. I wasn't able to change the adapter setting under network settings in the server's settings.